# Let's Encrypt HTTPS certificate on Wordpress subdomain reverse-proxied in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, ssl, heroku, lets-encrypt

I currently have a Let's Encrypt certificate up and running on my root domain, `https://www.myapp.com`, which is working and serving a Heroku-based Rails app.  The domain has a CNAME `www` to `www.myapp.com.herokudns.com`.

The site also has a Wordpress install running on `www.myapp.com/blog`, which forwards to `blog.myapp.com` using a reverse-proxy described [here](https://medium.com/@parterburn/wordpress-inside-a-ruby-on-rails-app-c324fbf39ad8#.xszaorbtm).  The domain has an A record `blog` pointing at the IP address of the host, a shared hosting server.

I used certbot and have already confirmed the certificate via the ACME challenge.  The cert includes both the root and subdomain.

Now I am at a loss as to how to get the subdomain to use the certificate.  A visit to `https://blog.myapp.com` shows the "Your connection is not private" warning in Chrome.

What steps are necessary to get the subdomain cert working?  I'm not sure I understand all the moving parts here and where to start. Thanks!

Edit for clarity:

Domain registrar: GoDaddy
Root domain: Heroku Rails app
Subdomain: Wordpress on HostGator

Comment: Did you configure your ssl certificate also on HostGator?

Comment: I had not!  Unfortunately after digging into that, I found this article which says only VPS/Dedicated plans can install their own certs: https://support.hostgator.com/articles/ssl-certificates/acquire-ssl/im-going-to-purchase-my-own-ssl-what-do-i-need-to-know

Comment: Does hostgator provide a default ssl cert? You don't need to use your own subdomain for the blog when you proxy it through your rails app. You can use the default domainname which your hoster provides.